# Google Play Console API return 'Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "versionCodes" at \'track_config\': Cannot find field.'

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-play-developer-api

I'm working a project in Ionic, Cordova and Angular, now I'm in the publishing process and need to automatize it using Google Play Console API, I released the second app version and I'm using Python3 and oauth2client and httplib2 libraries to upload the APK.

I'm using a variant of this [repository](https://gist.github.com/tayl0r/bbffbd0788a71cd4062482ab1c49c292) adapted to python3 and I generated the credentials to access to the API but when I run the script to upload the APK it gives me the following error:

> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting
> https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/com.somepackage.here/edits/ID_VERSION/tracks/beta?alt=json
> returned "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "versionCodes"
> at 'track_config': Cannot find field.". Details: "[{'@type':
> 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest', 'fieldViolations':
> [{'field': 'track_config', 'description': 'Invalid JSON payload
> received. Unknown name "versionCodes" at 'track_config': Cannot find
> field.'}]}]">

My code looks like the following:

```py
track_response = service.edits().tracks().update(
    editId=edit_id,
    track=TRACK,
    packageName=package_name,
    body={u'versionCodes': [apk_response['versionCode']]}).execute()
```

I'm really sure the problem is here.

I've been looking for help in some sites but it seems not to be documented, I found a related solution but to the Java library in [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/1527).

I will be thankful if you can help me.

Comment: My bad, I used an structure that was not according to the documentation: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-publisher-api/blob/master/v3/python/upload_apks_with_listing.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and after reading API docs I came to this solution:

```
    track_response = service.edits().tracks().update(
        editId=edit_id,
        track=TRACK,
        packageName=BUNDLE_ID,
        body={
            "track": TRACK,
            "releases": [
                {
                    "name": APP_NAME,
                    "versionCodes": [apk_response['versionCode']],
                    "status": "completed"
                 }
            ]
        }
    ).execute()
```

Comment: Thanks for aswer, I also share the original link where is the complete example I did something bad in the structure: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-publisher-api/blob/master/v3/python/upload_apks_with_listing.py